# R: list files based on pattern

Tags: regex, r

I want to list all files that start with "aT_" and have the extention ".tif" (e.g `aT_123456_1x1_abcdef.tif`):

```
files<- list.files(pattern="^aT_")
files<- list.files(pattern="\\.tif$")
```

How can I combine the patterns? Is there a wildcard for any kind of symbol: e.g 0-9,a-z, A-Z, _? Something like `files<- list.files(pattern="^aT_[any kind of symbol]\\.tif$")`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `.*` for matching any kind of character except line breaks.

```
files<- list.files(pattern="^aT_.*\\.tif$")
```

or

```
files<- list.files(pattern="^aT_\\w*\\.tif$")
```